# input and a on one click

Tags: jquery, html

So i have an `a href` that clears the filters and i have an `input` that sets the `value` of other filter as empty. On `a href` click i want it to also clear the other filter. I have tried multiple things but none of those were working. It may be done with `jQuery`, or pure `html`.

This is my `a href`:

```
<a href="#clear" class="btn clear-filter" title="clear filter">{translate}Clear{/translate}</a>
```

This is my `input` :

```
<label class="btn btn-status all-statuses active">
    <input class="filter-status" type="radio" name="options" value="" checked> {translate}All statuses{/translate}
</label>
```

How can i on one click connect them both to work on `a href` click ?

Comment: So what exactly is your question?

Comment: In one click I want to input and a work at the same time. So both filters are cleared.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it on click event of it.

```
$('.clear-filter').on('click', function() {
     $( ".filter-status" ).prop('checked', false);
});
```

Comment: This solution was exacly what i wanted. Thank you very much :)

Answer (score 1):

```js
$(document).on("click",".clear-filter",function(){
  $("input[name='options']").prop("checked",false);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<a class="btn clear-filter" title="clear filter">{translate}Clear CLICK ME{/translate}</a>

<br><br>
<label class="btn btn-status all-statuses active">
    <input class="filter-status" type="radio" name="options" value="" checked > {translate}All statuses{/translate}
</label>
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if that's true but w3schools tell me that this kind of name attributes is not supported in HTML5:
https://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_a_href.asp
It's under more Examples the first one

Answer (score 0):

have a link to a .js file and make a click event and then just do everything from there.

.html

```
<script src="main.js"></script>
```

main.js file

```
$('#clear').click(function() {

}
```

is a load of stuff you can google to help you do this but here is a basic one to get you going:
https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/event_onclick.asp

Happy Coding :)